# ggplot2 figure margins in LaTeX Beamer via Knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, knitr, sweave

I am currently playing with R and LaTeX via Knitr.

Trying to do a very simple slide deck with beamer, I run into a little issue. When I use the \includegraphics method to insert an image, it nicely takes the same width as the text length. However when I use R code to generate a ggplot2 chart, the chart width seems limited to something around 2/3 of the text length (which is very small with information heavy charts). This occurs even with a very wide figure width set up...

Is there a way to remove all additional margins that the R figures seems to add?

The code below reproduce the situation.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A sample slide}

Some text to show text length, Some text to show text length, Some text to show text length, Some text to show text length.

\begin{center}

<<figureExample, echo=False, fig=true, out.width=15>>=
library(ggplot2)
qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg, colour = factor(cyl)) + 
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill='green', colour='red')) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))
@

\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be super appreciated, I tried everything I could find :(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find the [documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) for knitr?

Comment: Hi jora, I did and thought at the time that "out.width" would do the tricks but no success. Will look again though. Thanks for mentionning it.

Comment: Well, you aren't using out.width in your example, and using that chunk option works for me. So you'll have to provide a more detailed example that demonstrates it not working. (Unrelated: you appear to be using a rather old version of ggplot2.)

Comment: You are right, I shall have used non-deprecated code (corrected). If you have time, could you please check the syntax of the "out.width"? It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's because you still haven't read the documentation: "for LaTeX output, they can be .8\\linewidth, 3in or 8cm". (Not those specific numbers, of course, but those are the formats it should be in.)

Comment: I actually tried that, with and without "" as well as some combination with textwidth instead of linewidth... I probably sound very lazy or dumb by now but I just cannot get it to scale yet...

Comment: Nope, changing out.width definitely changes the figure width for me. (Although, `\SweaveOpts` isn't valid in knitr I think, and I had to remove that to get your example to run at all.) You might also need to load the **grid** package in order for `unit` to work.

Comment: \SweaveOpts is added by RStudio everytime I compile the PDF. I will let it be for a day to see if I can find something, for now it really does not make sense (especially after working with the article document class, with which all seemed logical). My last guess is that the max width is calculated with some kind of default height-width ratio as target and not changed after. When I dont specify any width the chart fill the whole height. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yet another behavior that I can't reproduce. <shrug>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @joran mentioned in the comments, `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` is not supposed to be there. If RStudio insists on adding it to your document, I'm highly skeptical about your RStudio settings -- it seems you are using Sweave instead of `knitr` to compile this document (in that case, RStudio does add this if you have checked the concordance option). Go to `Tools -> Options -> Sweave`, and see if you have changed the default `Sweave` option to `knitr`.

Sweave sets the figure width to `.8\textwidth` globally by default, and that might explain the problem you saw.

Also note `echo=False, fig=true` are not valid `knitr` [chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options). You need to use `TRUE/FALSE`. For `out.width`, you'd better give it an explicit unit such as `in` or `cm`.

Comment: Hi Yihui, you were right: my RStudio was wrongly setup. Everything works now. Thank you so much for the answer (and the awesome knitr)!